# Puppeteer timeout 30000ms when headless is true

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, xserver, screensharing

I am running a bunch of web tests remotely, with Screen on a Ubuntu machine, running Lighthouse on a Puppeteer browser instance. Current setup used to work very fine until 2022 November when I ran tests last time, but when I tried it again a few days ago it started failing out with the following error;

```
TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r901912 is guaranteed to work.
    at Timeout.onTimeout (/home/jin/github/policy-driven-interventions/tools/web_crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:208:20)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7
```

DEBUG="puppeteer:*" reveals that the browser is never launched.

I immediately tried headless mode with the same configs, and it worked well. But I need headful tests, so that is not an option for me.

The monitor might have been disconnected from the computer (cannot confirm for now as I am away from the machine), and I guess this may have something to do with the failure. However, Google Chrome is launched without any problem on the same Screen session (this Screen session was initiated on the remote machine terminal, when the monitor was connected).

Outside of the Screen session, without display, the test fails with different error message as expected (meaning different thing caused the failure in the Screen session;

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[13675:13675:0402/034541.040435:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[13675:13675:0402/034541.040531:ERROR:env.cc(226)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/jin/github/policy-driven-interventions/tools/web_crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:197:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/jin/github/policy-driven-interventions/tools/web_crawler/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:188:79)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
```

Memory of the machine wouldn't be an issue as it has not been changed since when the tests were working, and its usage is quite low (6%).

My tests work fine with headful Puppeteer on my local Mac with the exact same code, so I guess my code is fine, unless there is any issue particularly related to Linux system.

What would be the source of the problem? Anyone has any insight?

For short, I suspect the following;

1. Disconnection of the monitor (Puppeteer and Google Chrome check the "display" in different ways)
2. Any Ubuntu (18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-197-generic x86_64))-related issue with old Puppeteer (v.10.4.0) and Google Chrome (v.103.0.5060.134)
3. What else??

Comment: What have you done about this error: `Error: Failed to launch the browser process!` , which is followed by `Missing X server or $DISPLAY` ?

Comment: @Luuk Sorry for the late response. I did nothing for that as that error comes up while I am out of a Screen session, but I always do my job in a Screen session.